# How to take full webpage screenshots with no size or length limit? (really long pages)

Tags: browser-addons, scrolling, screenshot, webpage, snapshot

How can I take full webpage screenshots with no size or length limit? I want to screenshot the search results on eBay with 200 items in view but it cuts off.

I have tried Firefox, Edge and Chrome's built-in tools, including their developer tools for full page screenshot, and various browser extensions, including "FireShot", "Save Screenshot" and "GoFullPage". None of them work for long pages like eBay (with the max 200 results shown). They all cut off the image.

It seems there may be a size limitation for all browsers, but is there any way around this? Is there anything that can be changed in the `about:config` or other setting areas to remove this limitation?

As an alternative I am currently saving webpages externally, but I much prefer the simplicity of a single image and the ability to notate it in image editors.

Any suggestions appreciated.

OS: Windows 10.

Comment: Print it to a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

There are add-ons for many browsers that produce more complete (and better formatted!) print-out of web pages. For example, for [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/), there is [Print Edit WE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=print), for [MS Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/search/print?hl=en-US) there's CloudPrint, etc.

Go to the *Extensions* or *Add-ons* tab of your browser and search on *print*.

It may take a bit of time to become familiar with all the features of an extension. You might need to manually select the print area, or to click a button to view test displayed through Javascript, etc.

**N.B.** An extension (add-on) an be malicious; read reviews before installing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Nimbus Capture" Firefox Extension and select Entire Page and you will get the complete webpage as screenshot which works for me all the time.

hope it helps.